# Reduce return empty array

Tags: node.js, arrays, asynchronous, mongoose

activeUsers - array of mongoose objects
activeUsers.campaings - array of mongoose objects
landingsFromBinom - array of objects where store id `[{id: 123, name: name}, {id: 133, name: name2}]`

For each user i have campaigns array (mongoose doc), for each campaigns i have langings array (mongoose doc).

I fetch all users from db and start iterate for each.
For each campaign i fetch 'landings' and start iterate for each.

Look at db and compare id's that i need to change and store it value in "landingsIds"

**PROBLEM**: when i console log "data" that returns me empty array, but if i console.log in function that return filled array. How to fix it?

```
 // Fetch users from db
  let activeUsers = await User.find().populate({
    path: 'campaigns',
    match: { active: true },
  })

  const data = activeUsers.reduce((results, user) => {
    // For each campaign get landings
    user.campaigns.forEach(async (campaign) => {
      const { landings } = await campaign.populate({
        path: 'landings',
        match: { active: true },
      })

      // Get only good ID
      const landingsIds = landings.reduce((results, landing) => {
        landingsFromBinom.forEach((binomLanding) => {
          if (
            parseInt(binomLanding.id) === landing.id &&
            binomLanding.inject >= landing.todayVisitors
          ) {
            results.push(landing.id)
          }
        })
        return results
      }, [])

      results.push({
        landings: landingsIds,
        user: user._id
      })
      // RETURN Filled array
      console.log(results)
    })
    return results
  }, [])

  // Return empty array
  console.log(data)
```

**Output** :

```
[]
[
  {
    landings: [ 3, 11, 1, 7 ],
    user: new ObjectId("617fb23b1e7ea187ae07a6ee")
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

use await in `array.reduce` with `Promise.resolve`

```
let activeUsers = await User.find().populate({
    path: 'campaigns',
    match: { active: true },
  })

  const data = await activeUsers.reduce(async (results, user) => {
    // For each campaign get landings
    user.campaigns.forEach(async (campaign) => {
      const { landings } = await campaign.populate({
        path: 'landings',
        match: { active: true },
      })

      // Get only good ID
      const landingsIds = landings.reduce((results, landing) => {
        landingsFromBinom.forEach((binomLanding) => {
          if (
            parseInt(binomLanding.id) === landing.id &&
            binomLanding.inject >= landing.todayVisitors
          ) {
            results.push(landing.id)
          }
        })
        return results
      }, [])

      results.push({
        landings: landingsIds,
        user: user._id
      })
      // RETURN Filled array
      console.log(results)
    })
   
  }, [], Promise.resolve(results))

  console.log(data)
```

Comment: returned undefined

Comment: Try again i update my answer